# Проблемы с кодировкой в exception message

Tags: c#, исключения, кодировка, visual-studio

Доброго времени суток, Хэшкод.

Найдено творчество неизвестного "надмозга" в Visual-Studio-2010. В результате его творчества, я ловлю в catch-е весьма информативную ошибку с сообщением:

> Ïàðàìåòð çàäàí íåâåðíî

Visual-Studio английская. Судя по поиску по HResult, эта должна быть:

> "The parameter is incorrect"

Видимо это перевод этой ошибки на русский с неправильной кодировкой.

В связи с этим, у меня два вопроса:

<s>1) Как перевести эту надпись в читаемый вид программный способом на c#? Просто хочу проверить свое предположение.</s> - решено

2)  Куда более важный вопрос: Как так получилось, что в английской версии VS внезапно вылезла ошибка с надписью на русском языке? Просто ошибка получилась крайне мерзкая, "плавающая" и любые догадки могут мне быть полезны.

З.Ы. Сам косяк возникает при Insert-е объекта в коллекцию Item-ов на UI, причем не всегда(плавающий же). Подробно пока не описываю, мне важнее узнать ответ на №2.

---

О, я применил свои невероятные способности дешифровальшика и понял, что было написано в ошибке:

> Параметр задан неверно

Но это так, к слову.

---

Чуть подробнее про вылет:

```
 foreach (Something x in list)
   {
    // делаем что-то, создаем объект control
    this.MainScreen.Items.Insert(somePredefinedIndex + i, control);
    /* Вставляем на текущую страницу в ListBox по имени MainScreen элемент на некую позицию */
    i++;
   }
```

В *некоторых* случаях при Insert вылазит вот эта ошибка. Нашел два таких стабильных случая. Закономерности пока не вижу.

Comment: Насчёт пункта 1 не скажу, но пункт 2 может быть вызван тем, что у вас установлена русская версия .NET Framework. Там все тексты ошибок переведены на русский.

Comment: Очень странно. Все строки в .NET Unicode. Может, вы её неправильно выводите как-то? Приведите релевантный код.

---
Похоже на преобразование CP1251 -> ANSI для системной кодовой страницы, не содержащей русских символов.

Comment: @VladD, вывод действительно был сделан немного оригинально. Там был использован ToastPrompt из сторонней библиотеки от Coding4Fun. Но сейчас я сделал вывод с помощью *MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);* и вывелись аналогичные кракозябры...

Comment: @Olter: хм. А откуда пришло исключение? Не из нативного кода случайно?

Comment: Такое происходит, когда в настройках винды для non-Unicode программ установлена не русская локализация. Настройка Control Panel -> Change keyboards or other input methods -> Administrative -> Change system locate.

Comment: @MaLS: эээ... .NET framework весь Unicode-ный, так что проблема где-то ниже.

Comment: @VladD а как можно определить, что исключение пришло именно из native code? (и сравнивать с чем? С байт-кодом?) З.Ы. Обновил там часть про вылет, не знаю, поможет ли :). P.P.S. Items это ItemCollection. (*System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection*)

Comment: @Olter: а какого типа Items?

Comment: @Olter: смотрю при помощи ILSpy:

    class ItemCollection
    {
        public void Insert(int insertIndex, object insertItem)
        {
         this.CheckIsUsingInnerView();
         this._internalView.Insert(insertIndex, insertItem);
            this.ModelParent.SetValue(ItemsControl.HasItemsPropertyKey, BooleanBoxes.TrueBox);
        }
    }

Comment: @Olter: подозрение, конечно, на `this._internalView.Insert(insertIndex, insertItem);`. Оно является на самом деле `MS.Internal.Controls.InnerItemCollectionView.Insert`: http://pastebin.com/JnsvyiXz. Тут подозрение на `this._viewList.Insert(index, item);`, которое есть `ArrayList.Insert`. Попробуйте сделать похожую ошибку с `ArrayList` (index out of bounds?) и глянуть, та же проблема или нет.

Comment: @Olter: кстати, если вы ставите breakpoint в catch, и смотрите текст исключения, та же проблема?

Comment: Да, при проверке breakpoint-а та же проблема. З.Ы. Нашел на SO [этот][1] вопрос (ответчик подозрительно знаком, кстати :)), но что-то не пойму, как поставить Mixed Mode. хм


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354411/debugging-native-code-when-called-from-managed

Comment: @Olter: :-)

Там по ссылке:

> To enable mixed-mode debugging:
>
> 1. In Solution Explorer, select the project.
> 2. On the View menu, click Property Pages.
> 3. In the Project Property Pages dialog box, expand the Configuration Properties node, and then select Debugging.
> 4. Set Debugger Type to Mixed or Auto.

Comment: Да, да, я именно про то, что по ссылке. Не вижу где Debugger type проставляется. И, кстати, Configuration properties это же раздел для Solution-а, а не для проекта.

Comment: @Olter: А, да, это для C++/CLI. Для C# Project settings -> Debug -> Enable unmanaged code debugging. Но в нативный код библиотек оно, я думаю, всё равно не зайдёт, т.к. у вас нет исходников. Их можно скачать и заставить VS таки заходить.

Comment: @Olter: вот документация по этому поводу: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Локализация ошибок выполнения зависит от языковых настроек ОС и фреймворка. Таким образом, если у вас установлен какой-либо language-pack для .Net и он совпадает с настройками ОС, то вы будете получать локализованное сообщение.

Самый простой способ - удалить language-pack.

Если после этого ответа всё ещё хочется поиграться, то загляните в [CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture.aspx). Хотя, оно вам надо?

Comment: Не понял, причем тут "ошибки компилятора", если эта радость вылазит в exception.message? Тем более, что как раз ошибки компилятора у меня все на английском.

Comment: Экскузе муа, неверно написал. Конечно, у вас ошибки выполнения. Но это в целом ничего не меняет.